# How can I calculate the time (%) to submit a form/file using an iframe?

Tags: html, forms, iframe

Suppose I have a form inside an iframe and I'll submit this form. Is there a way to get the time been wasted or % of the data being sent?

Comment: If sending a form is taking long enough to warrant a progress bar... something is seriously wrong. Just put a nice "Please wait, sending data..." message and the user will wait a good fifteen seconds or more before thinking there might be a problem.

Comment: No, there is no problem. I want to make a progress bar but don't know how to get the time (%).

Comment: @TheZ In the title OP states it is (also) about files being uploaded (at least that how I read it).

Comment: Oh I see, this might help: http://devpro.it/upload_progress/